# How can i debug code that invoked with java reflection?

Tags: java, debugging, reflection

I hava an application which deployed on J2EE application server , inside the application there is implementation of class loader loading jar files into the JVM, inside those jar files there are Test Cases which implements common interface, by java reflection i dynamically invoke (by name) those test cases, the problem is that is like a black box and if test case fails i need to work hard to find what went worng throw the application server logger , is there any way to debug the test cases code? or any suggestion at all? thank you sorry for the long story..

Comment: Why do you have to launch the Test Cases through reflection, rather than simply by running them trough a standard TestRunner ? Is it because the jar files are uploaded to your server at run-time ?

Comment: could you elaborate how the test-setup/run is done (i hope a proper build-system is used, which usually gives good reporting about test-outcomes). as above mentioned you should launch your test-cases in a standard way.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use Java's remote debugging facility.  I've done something similar before and I would simply set a breakpoint in the test that failed.  This [page](http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-debug-remote-java-applicat) describes how to set up remote debugging in eclipse.  How you enable debugging depends on the app server you're using.

Comment: Heres another article covering remote debugging in ecplise.
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-javadebug/index.html

Answer (score -1):

You can connect to a remote Java EE app server with IntelliJ and step through the code line by line.